# How to customize theme in the instance configuration?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

The [customizing theme Vuetify's guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/theme) not show a complete one-page-code, and when I try the clues, no is working. See trying-example at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/ppKrauss/pen/yKYrEM).

```html
<div id="app" light> 
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-card color="primary"> <!-- need to CHANGE here! -->
            <v-card-text><b>Hello</b> - test 123 </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 >
           <v-card dark color="secondary">
             <v-card-text>Bye  - test.</v-card-text>
           </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Using the clues of the guide, no effect

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify, {  // IGNORING ALL
  theme: {
    primary: 'red',
    secondary: '#b0bec5',
    accent: '#8c9eff',
    error: '#b71c1c'
  }
});
new Vue({    // NO EFFECT HERE
  el: '#app',
});
```

NOTE: trying also other like

```
var xx = new Vue({ el: '#app' })
xx.use(Vuetify, { theme: {...} })
```

but no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publisher's will usually call `use` when using the CDN. In order for this to work you will need apply it to each `Vue` instance, which you can do in the `created` hook:

```
const theme = {
    primary: '#f44336',
    secondary: '#b0bec5',
    accent: '#8c9eff',
    error: '#b71c1c'
}

var xx = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created() {
     this.$vuetify.theme = theme
  }
})
```

Also note, that the `vuetify` colors won't work here, you need the hex value. Fortunately, you can find all the appropriate material design colors at: https://www.materialui.co/colors

Here's your [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvMPZL)

Comment: Thanks @craig_h, now I can see that the Vuetify-magic for *customizing theme* is `created(){this.$vuetify.theme=TheNewTheme}` !   There are something comment at [vuetifyjs.com/style/theme](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/theme), but is only a indirect comment (about  how to change primary color)... As a guide, it need **some enhance** and a full-example, as the your. Need a big notice to say **Customize = `set  $vuetify.theme`**... So I post [this issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetifyjs.com/issues/351).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // customize vuetify globally
    Vue.prototype.$vuetify.theme = {
        primary: '#f44336',
        secondary: '#b0bec5',
        accent: '#8c9eff',
        error: '#b71c1c'
    }
</script>
```

Try this, you don't need to customize every Vue instance.
Refer: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html